# How to find and replace specific lines of HTML in a batch

Tags: html

Does anyone know or have any suggestions on how to batch find and replace specific lines of HTML? My problem is that I have several hundred HTML files each of them with a line (line 25) which needs to be replaced with the same code. The problem is that the code that it is replacing is:

```
<p>nbsp;</p>
```

Which occurs several times throughout the file, which is necessary, but I only want to change one of them. All the batch replacers that I have found so far would overwrite the other instances that are necessary.

Any suggestions would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure the replacement is on line 25th? or is there any particular identifier word or something else?

Comment: Do you want to replace them permanently or want to replace them while they are running on server

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutley sure about the position of your needle, you can just strip your html into an array and replace the 25th entry:

```
html = html.split("\n");
html[24] = "replaced";
return html.join("\n");
```